# DynamoDb Table get_item

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have the following meta data in my dynamodb table

```
{'num_items': 5, 'primary_key_name': {'AttributeName': 'report_name', 'KeyType': 'HASH'}
```

I have the following function from the boto3 documentation

```
def read_table_item(table_name, pk_name, pk_value):
    """
    Return item read by primary key.
    """
    dynamodb_resource = resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2')
    table = dynamodb_resource.Table(table_name)
    response = table.get_item(Key={pk_name: pk_value})

    return response
```

I am having issues constructing the `pk_name` and `pk_value`

I am confused on how to pass the primary key to get my item.

the error I am getting is

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the GetItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema
```

I am currently passing in the `pk_key` as such

```
pk_name = {'AttributeName': 'report_name', 'KeyType': 'HASH'}
pk_value = "Test Report"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use 'AttributeName' or 'KeyType'.

It should look like this:

```
Key={ 'report_name': "Test Report" }
```

Here is an example on how to do it:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.03.html#GettingStarted.Python.03.02

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the type of pk_value according to the schema, so your request should look like this:

```
response = table.get_item(Key={pk_name:{'S':str(pk_value)}})
```